# Can I use xaml binging without ui? without derive from control?

Tags: c#, xaml

I want to use xaml to build my workflow like this to split the workflow design and functions.

```
<Command x:Class="MyCommand">
  <Step1 Name="">
     <Step2 />
  </Step1>
</Command/>
```

it works.
but when I want to get a value may be updated, i must write a event:

```
<Command x:Class="MyCommand">
  <Step1  GetName="OnGetName">
     <Step2 />
  </Step1>
</Command/>
void OnGetName(out string name){name = "xxx";}
```

I think wpf's binding is very well for me ,but sine there are no window, my classes are not inherit from control, It cannot work, event I make my classes inherit from DependencyObject.

Is there any way to import a binding like method?

---

I update my question as maybe a complete new question.
My real request is use xaml binding without window.

at beginning, I don't want to inherit from Control or FrameworkElement. bug I find it is impossible.

now I update my code to inherit from FrameworkElement, it can work by write binding, but event not with xaml.

```
public class Command : FrameworkElement
{
       public static readonly DependencyProperty Test1Property = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(Test1), typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

        public string Test1
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(Test1Property); }
            set { SetValue(Test1Property, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty Test2Property = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(Test2), typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

        public string Test2
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(Test2Property); }
            set { SetValue(Test2Property, value); }
        }
}
```

I add a window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d" x:Name="Main"
        DataContext="{x:Reference Main}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <local:UserControl1 x:Name="Control" Test1="{Binding TestStr, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"></local:UserControl1>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and init the Test2 binding by code:

```
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var binding = new Binding("TestStr")
            {
                Source = this,
            };
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(Control, UserControl1.Test2Property, binding);

            TestStr = "XXS";

            MessageBox.Show($"ONLoad: Test1: {Control.Test1}, Test2: {Control.Test2}");
}
```

then if I new the MainWindow, without Show(), I get the MessageBox show

```
Test1:, Test2:XXS
```

I want to find a way to make the xaml binding work before show()!

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I want to use binding without ui.

Comment: I work with a cad system as plugins, the interaction is  cad drawing such as pick point or input. I want to split the workflow and data. I find write the workflow as xml is clear.